# How to create an iOS in-app purchase with Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have been googling all over the place, both inside Titanium docs, and elsewhere. All the support/forum pages I found related to handling In App iOS purchases contain dead links to missing pages.

Can someone point me to current and relevant documentation for Titanium Appcelerator iOS In App purchases?

Specifically I just need to know the basics:

1. How can I link a button to trigger an in-app purchase?
2. How can I capture the successful purchase, and know who did it so I can give them credit in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `ti.storekit` module from Appcelerator. It can be installed through [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/component/ti.storekit) or just download the release from the [github](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.storekit/releases) page.

An example can be found in the example [app.js](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.storekit/blob/master/ios/example/app.js) file found in the download, or on github.